# Secure the content of my QR Code

Tags: security, qr-code

I am developing a game, based on QR codes/NFC.
I'd like to be sure, if somebody read our tag, or qr, that is our tag/qr not a copy of it.

The concept of my system is to place a unique ID on the tag/qr, and when user reads it with the phone, phone is sending this ID to our server through HTTPS post request.

For NFC, I think, I can handle it. I store the serial number and the unique ID of tag in a database, and I can compare the stored ID/serial pairs with the sent ID/serial pair, and if it matches, then that is our tag. This is because, if somebody read our NFC tag with any tool, like NFC Tools app, it can send the unique ID to anybody through email, and the receiver can create a copy of that tag, but serial will not match. So I think this is the best way to be sure to secure the NFC part of my problem. (Tell me if it's not the matter).

But I am afraid I cannot handle the QR part of my problem. Because I'm just sending a link through QR to the APP, I have no possibility to do the mentioned method for QR. Anybody can read the content of the QR and create a copy of it.

Does anybody know a technique about this for QR?

Answer (score 0):

A QR code is just a image which contains data.  There is no way to stop a user taking a photo and then sharing that code - or the data inside it.

There is really only one things you can do.

When a QR code is scanned, you should invalidate any further scans.  The second person to scan the code should be told "This code has already been used".

Comment: The point of the game is to allow users to scan qr codes, even if somebody scanned it before. I just want to prevent them to share the ID, because i want the user to be there physically. This is a time based game, so everybody can scan it, but who collect X piece of a code, and do it faste then others, he win.

The first 3 will win, and in this case, they can cheat :(